# Find date difference in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am having problem for calculating date difference.And I have used jquery .

Jquery

```
$("#leave_apply_day_count").on("click",function(){
  var from = $('#leave_apply_from_date').val();
  var to   = $('#leave_apply_to_date').val();
  var url  = '/leave_applies/new?from_date='+from+'&to='+to + ''

   $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){

        $("#leave_apply_day_count").val(data);  
   }
  });
})
```

Controller

```
if params[:from_date].present?
     @from_date = params[:from_date].to_i
     @to_date = params[:to].to_i
     @count = @from_date - @to_date
    end
```

I have used this code. but I am not getting right output.

Comment: Are you working here with date strings or timestamps?

Comment: I am using date string.

Comment: And what kind of output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you wanted the number of days between two dates:

```
from_date = Date.parse(params[:from_date]) # Format: '2013-09-23'
to_date = Date.parse(params[:to_date])
diff_days = from_date.mjd - to_date.mjd
```

Comment: I am having doubt in calculating count.It should eliminate Saturday and sundays